# ItunesConnect Ready for Sale invaild version in AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

i have problem. I have released update for my app (version 1.1) in itunesconnect i have status: ready for sale (for 36h from now). And in AppStore everyone have 1.0 - me too. How long it should take, i mean change version for new one?

Comment: Are you sure you set it to auto publishing or maybe you have to press he green go button so it is actually sold...?

Comment: Im sure. I made it before, with other apps. And both options I used, I know how to use. Any idea what to do?